# How can I search by specific category selected by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to let the user select a category (3 in total) and then search for items in that category only.

Image for reference: https://ibb.co/zRspdFs

So, when a user clicks on, for example category 1, and then clicks on the form input, the search should show items from the selected category.

For now I have some dummy data as value for the input field. and I can retrieve values from the dropdown selection. But I don't know how to filter the search.

```js
var availableTags = [
  "mama",
  "tata",
  "PAPI"
];

$('#menu li').click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#custId").val(value);
});

$("#searcher").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  minLength: 0
}).click(function() {
  $(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form class="form-inline col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
  <svg class="svg-custom" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                            </svg>
  <input class="input-custom srch form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search by Keywords" id="searcher" aria-label="Search">

  <div class="search-dropper">
    <span class="icon-down-open-mini arrow-search"></span>
    <ul id="menu" class="search-dropdown">
      <a class="" href="#">
        <li value="1">1</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li value="2">2</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li value="3">3</li>
      </a>
      <li>
        <input type="hidden" id="custId" name="custId" value="3487">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make array that contains list of items that you can pass to autocomplete after category is selected?

eg:

```
var availableTags = [
    "mama",
    "tata",
    "PAPI"
];

var categories = [
[searchItem1, searchitem2...],
[searchItem1, searchitem2...],
[searchItem1, searchitem2...]
]
```

On category select you take index, and you pull searchable items by index, and then pass that to autocomplete:

```
$( "#searcher" ).autocomplete({
  source: categories[indexOfCategory]
});
```

Im sure there is a bit cleaner solution, jquery is not my specialty, but you can do something like this

Comment: @Filu no problem. Glad i helped :)